# What expression am I missing? and I'm returning the type

Tags: objective-c, return

Here is my main function. It is saying that it reaches the end of the readRecord function and doesn't get a return type? The error is below. I am returning a typedef struct called Movie. its defined in support.h with the variables listed below in the readRecord function. I have tried defining the readRecord in support.h but it did not help.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "scanner.h"
#include "support.h"

Movie *readRecord(FILE*);

main(int argc, char** argv)
{
FILE *fp = fopen("test.xlt", "r");
readRecord(fp);

return 0;
}

Movie *
readRecord(FILE *fp)
{
char *name;

name = readString(fp);
if(feof(fp)) {return 0;}

Movie *m = malloc(sizeof(Movie));

m->name = name;
m->description = readString(fp);
m->year = readInt(fp);
m->length = readInt(fp);
m->rating = readToken(fp);
m->cast = readString(fp);
m->director = readString(fp);

return Movie *;
}
```

in the terminal:

```
$ gcc -Wall -g level1.c scanner.c -o level1
level1.c: In function ‘readRecord’:
level1.c:35:12: error: expected expression before ‘Movie’
      return Movie *;
            ^
level1.c:36:5: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to return the object, in your variable `m`, not it's type `Movie *`, ie.

```
return m;
```